# Display an ASCII value of a given character

Tags: java, ascii

I wrote a Java web based program to display ASCII value of given character. but it is not
working properly. pls help me. this is my code. no need to add characters to the database.

main bean

```
public mainbean() {}

private String charTest;

public String getCharTest() {
    return charTest;
}

public void setCharTest(String charTest) {
    this.charTest = charTest;
}

public String DoDisplay() throws IOException {

    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

   //  System.out.println("Enter the char:");
    // String str = buff.readLine();
    String str = buff.readLine();

     // for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i){
    int i = 0;
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    int j = (int) c;
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "ASCII OF" + c + "=" + j, ""));
    return null;
}
```

this is my xhtml page

```xhtml
<h:head>
    <title>Complain System</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <h:outputText value="name"/>
        <p:inputText value="#{mainbean.charTest}"/>
        <p:commandButton value="submit" ajax="false" action="#{mainbean.doDisplay()}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

This is Ctrl page

```
public class charCtrl {

    private EntityManager em;

    public static void add() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String str = buff.readLine();
        int i = 0;
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        int j = (int) c;
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "ASCII OF" + c + "=" + j, ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define, "*not working properly*".

Comment: "_it is not working properly_" Is not a good enough problem description.

Comment: it displays text feild and and button. but when i enter a character and click check button it says " method doDisplay() is not found.

Comment: That's a lot of code for this question. Would you mind reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Doing this makes it _much_ easier to get good answers quickly.

Comment: You're not using ASCII. Replace "ASCII" with "UTF-16 code unit".

Answer (score 1):

you can try
1.) String.valueOf(ch).codePointAt(0);
2.) cast the character with int

Comment: from where do i enter this code? main bean or xhtml code?

Comment: in place of int j = (int) c;

Answer (score 0):

You can typecast your `char` as an `int`. So:

```
int asciiVal = (int) yourChar;
```

Sample code:

```
char yourChar = 'a';
int asciiVal = (int) yourChar;
System.out.println("ASCII for " + yourChar + " is " + asciiVal);
```

Comment: it display some error as " #{mainbean.doDisplay()}": Method doDisplay not found" what should i do? pls help me..

Comment: change the name of your method from "DoDisplay" to "doDisplay"